# AspNet Core AppInsights Integration

Tags: asp.net-core, inversion-of-control, azure-application-insights, simple-injector, telemetry

I am integrating app insights into our AspNet Core app(Target Framework .Net 4.7.1).  I have two queries regarding app insights integration.

1. I am using SimpleInjector IOC, so does it make sense to have below line of code to inject AI into Asp Net Core DI?

   services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry

I'm having my own Logger class which initializes TelemetryCLient and Logger class is injected using SimpleInjector. So removing above line code will cause an issue or lack of feature from ASPNet Core perspective?

2. In Asp.Net when we use to add AI it uses to add ApplicationInsights.config file which contains TelemetryInitializer's and TelemetryModules. Whats the best parctice in AspNet Core 2.1 for this? How do I add following TelemetryInitializers?

   - HttpDependenciesParsingTelemetryInitializer
   - AzureRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer
   - AzureWebAppRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer
   - OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer
     etc...

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

1. `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry` is the easiest way to add application insights to your project. It sets up auto-collection modules for Requests, Dependencies etc, sets up default TelemetryInitializers, TelemetryProcessors (for sampling, live metrics etc.)
   if you don't use `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry`, then you have to programmatically setup all modules/initializers/sampling etc yourself.
2. There is no ApplicationInsights.config file, so pretty much every customization of the config is to be done through code. Following shows how to add/remove telemetry initializers.
   https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Custom-Configuration#configure-telemetry-initializers